# What type of pepper is this?

Tags: identification, peppers

I have a pepper plant and I don't know what variety it is. Maybe someone can help me identify it. Some details about pictures and plant:

- 3.7 liter pot
- plant size is ~40 cm (~15 inches)
- fruit are 5-10 cm long (2-4 inches)
- fruit ripen from green to bright orange
- fruit have a very tough skin
- fruit are quite hot (hotter than Serrano pepper)
- plant loves sun more than my Serrano/Fresno peppers (40°C (100°F) in the sun is no problem)

[image: unknown pepper plant variety]
[image: unknown pepper plant fruit (orange)]

I have a second plant that I think is the same variety but it's fruit ripen from green to bright yellow:

[image: unknown pepper plant fruit (yellow)]

I can provide additional pictures/information if necessary.

Comment: What do they taste like?

Comment: @Shule I'm not sure since they are a little to hot for me to eat one raw.

Comment: Shoot, I just remembered a pepper that might fit!!  I grew a few last year...some silly weird name like 'salad pepper'...I'll go check my seed stash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be any of countless varieties, since there are thousands of kinds of peppers. However, it could be a Bulgarian Carrot chile pepper ([do an image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=bulgarian+carrot+pepper&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch)), by the appearance and your heat description. Some people think they're very mild, but some think they're extremely hot. I saw a YouTube video of a couple guys who tried them, thinking they would be about as hot as a jalapeno. You could really tell they were in pain. The variable heat could be due to growing conditions, but there are other factors.

Another noted similarity is that they start green and then turn orange. (Many peppers start yellow; so, this is good to know.)

The only other pepper I'm personally familiar with offhand that it sort of looks like is [Randy Sine's Evil Jalapeno F3](https://www.mariannasheirloomseeds.com/seed-catalog/special-crosses/evil-jalapeno-detail.html), which is still not stabilized and can be orange or red, depending on which seed you use. By the look of it (from my peppers; not the picture), I would guess it's part Bulgarian Carrot, personally, but it has an amazingly good jalapeno taste (and depending on the pepper it can have next to no heat, or be super hot). With these, they go green to orange, and when they're more ripe, the orange turns a bit more yellow to my eyes. I know the picture in the link I gave doesn't look much like your pepper, but my peppers that I grew this year look similar (from one of my plants; the other plant has red peppers). Bulgarian Carrot is a much more likely match, however.

Comment: Bulgarian Carrot could be it I think. They also can be yellow when ripe apparently. Although they look a little more inflated on the images I can find but maybe that's because my plant is in a small pot?

Answer (score 1):

Yup need more scale but I am pretty sure this is either Serrano or Cayenne peppers.  Did you plant this from seed or from seeding out of a store? What size pot is that?  6" or larger?  Then not cayenne.  Another one of us on this site will know, just send something for scale.

I agree with Shule!!  Out of all these PEPPER varieties, this is what I was going to suggest.  Here is a great site to check out...need to see and bisect the flower for positive ID on variety but when I saw that Bulgarian Carrot I saw the resemblance...yummm!!

[lots of pics of peppers to purvey and pick](https://www.cayennediane.com/big-list-of-hot-peppers/)

Comment: It's not Cayenne and not Serrano, this much I know. And what do you mean, "need more scale". Is the provided data not enough?

Comment: Sorry can't see the size of these peppers.  If you are sure about what they are not, I'm just hangin' to find what some of these other wizards say!!  Seriously.

Comment: OP mentions the size of the peppers in their question: _"fruit are 5-10 cm long (2-4 inches)"_

Comment: All I did was fix your broken link.